# Как инициализировать сразу несколько объектов?

Tags: c#, объекты, инициализация

```
Class MyClass
{}

MyClass a,b,c,d,e;
```

Как сразу их проинициализировать? Чтобы не писать на каждый

```
a = new MyClass();
b = new MyClass();
....
```

А если массив таких объектов делать, то придется циклом делать инициализацию каждого?

Хотя на код:

```
MyClass[] b = new MyClass[5];
b[1].MyMethod("sdf");
```

Компилятор не ругается, но вряд ли работать будет?

Comment: `А если массив таких объектов делать, то придется циклом делать инициализацию каждого?` - да

Comment: Если классов всего пару штук, то не составит труда руками их проинициализировать. Если классов много, то для этого обычно используют коллекции (`List<T>`) например, где при добавление нового объекта в ходе выполнения программы, делается инициализация. В вашем же случае (`MyClass[]`), да, надо сначала проинициализировать, а потом использовать.

Comment: А с какой целью интересуетесь? Если нужно для тестирования обычно перегружают конструктор (можно и без этого, но так легче фиксить после), и потом в цикле инициализируют "кучу" объектов.

Comment: `MyClass[] b = new MyClass[5];`, компилятор ругаться и не будет, с чего бы ему ругаться, если вы определяете массив с типом `MyClass` с размером `[5]` элементов. Вот если этот массив будет пустой после компиляции и попытки вызова несуществующего `b[1]` индекса и `MyMethod`, вам выдаст ошибку. А вообще, советую глянуть в сторону [делегатов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Comment: @AND у меня итак нагромождение!!! Свой класс чисел создал. Неудобно каждый раз инициализацию делать. Опыта мало, struct, возможно лучше будет чем класс.

Comment: Какие нагромождения? Свой класс чисел? Вы говорите загадками. Вы видимо не так задали вопрос.

Comment: Если кол-во классов известно используйте `static class` они инициализируются  сразу при запуске, но существуют только в одном экземпляре